# Developing app where you have to navigate through the file system

Tags: linux, groovy, windows-10, cd

I am developing this app in Groovy where it is necessary for the user to be able to move around the file system, whether the app is working in Linux or in W10. It's currently a command line app.

I am essentially coding something which mimics the operation of BASH/Windoze command `cd`. This is made rather irksome because of having to test which OS is currently involved.  Not to mention fiddly complications at the level of testing classes, e.g. in W10 going `Runtime.runtime.exec( 'pwd' )` in fact produces a file path in Cygwin format ("/cygdrive/d/...") which you then have to convert to a regular W10 format ("D:...").

One of my main classes thus has a field `pwd`, which is a File.  So it's a sort of pseudo-"present working directory". You change its location by pseudo-cd-ing

Just wondered if there's some module or something that can be enlisted... because this is donkey work really: you might have thought someone would have developed something you could just "slot in" to your app.

Or maybe I'm taking completely the wrong approach: maybe there's a better way of allowing the user to navigate the file system within an app... ?

Comment: Can't you use Path instead of File? Then you get useful methods such as `resolve`  and `normalize`

Comment: Abstracting the current working directory and modifying it feels more like you should go the groovy/java route instead of doing that via windows/cygwin/linix "APIs".  Keep a File or Path as the state the user is in and then use the java/groovy APIs to go from there.

Comment: Uh... interesting thoughts, food for thought.  Thanks for the suggestions.  "use the java/groovy APIs to go from there".  The trouble with that is that I've had a couple of glasses of wine (UK: evening).  Maybe I'll understand what you mean tmrw morning!

Comment: @tim_yates Tx.  Have been a "late adopter" of nio.file.  But this requirement of mine lends itself perfectly to the nio.file classes. Having resolved a new `Path` with the "rest of the line" after "cd" mostly it will be the case that if `Files.exists( ...)` and `Files.isDirectory( ... )` are both true that's it: you can reset the `pseudoPwdPath`.  Exceptions are things like "~", "/" and "\" (if you want something which works in W10 and Linux)... but dealing with these becomes trivial.